Generating Monthly Totals across multiple sheets
I have a daily report that is used for work that contains information like date, item costs, a daily total cost etc.
As its a daily report, its 1 sheet per day. To streamline getting monthly totals I am wondering if there is a way to sum all the "daily total costs" for the month.
With some months being 31 days, it would take a wile to do manually. Not sure if there is a VBA or macro that could be set up to help out.
I think it would be something like "=Sheet1!a2+Sheet2!a2+Sheet3!a2 etc.")
However I am hoping to have it give me the sum based on the month.

Is the date contained in the sheet name ? Does the workbook have only 1 month

The date is contained in the sheet, but not the name.
The sheets are named "Day 1, Day 2 etc."
The reports are project specific and can vary from a couple days to 8 months.

=SUM('Day 1:Day 30'!A1)  Will sum A1 from all sheets between "Day 1" and "Day 30" (inclusive)

Yes, you can do this either with VBA or with Excel formulas.

Or A1 from all sheets named "Day [1-31]", regardless of position: =SUM(IFERROR(CELL("contents",INDIRECT("'Day " & SEQUENCE(31,1) & "'!$A$1")),0))  The CELL workaround for using INDIRECT in an array formula is from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505923/using-indirect-function-with-dynamic-array-formula-syntax-excel-o365

=SUM('Day 1:Day 30'!A1)
will sum A1 from all sheets between "Day 1" and "Day 30" (inclusive), assuming there are no "extra" sheets between Day 1 and Day 30 which should not be included in the sum.
=SUM(IFERROR(CELL("contents",INDIRECT("'Day " & SEQUENCE(31,1) & "'!$A$1")),0))
Will sum A1 from any sheets named "Day [1-31]" regardless of their position in the workbook.
The CELL workaround for using INDIRECT in an array formula is from: using INDIRECT function with dynamic array formula syntax (Excel O365)

Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.

Thanks to everyone for giving me the suggestions. I was hoping to just use a VBA Macro and a button on Excel to just generate the current month. But I didnt figure that out, however the formulas given did help me out.
I used:
=SUM('Day 1:Day 30'!A1)
With some of our daily reports being for 200+ day projects, we will just use the last day (i.e. 195) and subtract the number of days in the month (i.e. 30).
=SUM('Day 165:Day 195'!A1) and get the values needed.
